# Значение свойства control.Visible равно false, если форма Windows Forms скрыта. Нормально ли это?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма с **GroupBox**, значение свойства **Visible** которого устанавливается в ***true*** (элемент фактически виден пользователю). Форма отображается в виде модального диалога, а после закрытия формы происходит считывание значения свойства **Visible**:

```
FormGB frm = new FormGB();
frm.GroupBox.Visible = true;
frm.ShowDialog();
bool vis = frm.GroupBox.Visible;    //vis равно false
```

Является ли нормальным такое поведение Control'a? Например, свойство **Enabled** не меняет своего состояния при скрытии формы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это нормально.

Смотрим исходники свойства [Visible](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,240089e1631214fc).

Внутри вызывается метод [GetVisibleCore](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,240089e1631214fc):

```
internal virtual bool GetVisibleCore() {
    // We are only visible if our parent is visible
    if (!GetState(STATE_VISIBLE))
        return false;
    else if (ParentInternal == null)
        return true;
    else
        return ParentInternal.GetVisibleCore();
}
```

Комментарий в коде недвусмысленен.

Comment: А вот в исходники заглянуть я не догадался... Спасибо огромное, теперь всё ясно!